# Are there any way to stop Unity from upgrading a shader?

Tags: unity, shaders

A projector shader using the `_Projector` attribute will be changed to use `unity_Projector`, instead, in Unity 5.5. I'm writing an editor plugin that works on multiple versions of Unity. Such upgrading will make the shader not work in earlier version of Unity.

Is there any way to stop such upgrading?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prevent Unity from upgrading a shader by adding `UNITY_SHADER_NO_UPGRADE` somewhere in the shader, like in a comment at the top of the file. This was added in Unity 5.4.

Comment: Just found this: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-BuiltinMacros.html. It also helps.